# How can you tell the source of the data when using the Stream.BeginRead Method?

Tags: c#, stream, beginread

When using the Stream.BeginRead Method, and you are reading from a stream into a memory, how is it determined where you are reading the data from?

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx

In the list of parameters, I do not see one that tells where the data is being read from:

### Parameters

- buffer Type: System.Byte[] The buffer to read the data into.
- offset Type: System.Int32 The byte offset in buffer at which to begin writing data read from the stream
- count Type: System.Int32 The maximum  number of bytes to read.
- callback Type: System.AsyncCallback    An optional  asynchronous callback, to    be called when the read is complete.
- state Type: System.Object A    user-provided object that      distinguishes this particular      asynchronous read request from other 
  requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads the data from wherever the stream is up to, as determined by the [`Position` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx).

Note that not all streams support seeking, so you cannot necessarily set `Position`.